# How to handle enable/disable of button which are in itemtemplate of ListView using MVVM?

Tags: wpf, mvvm

I am having ListView control which has button collections inside itemtemplate and want to handle the enable and disable of each button on ViewModel.

Comment: This is handled by command binding in MVVM.  Read [this section of this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx#id0090030).  Somebody can expound in an answer if they wish.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My best advice would be: use a [command](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx#id0090030) (I usually use Prism's [`DelegateCommand`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.practices.prism.commands.delegatecommand%28PandP.40%29.aspx) or [`DelegateCommand<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg431410%28PandP.40%29.aspx), you can download [Prism](http://nuget.org/packages/Prism) package via NuGet which makes it literally painless).

You then bind your button's command to the command:

```
<Button Command="{Binding MyCommand}" />
```

The [`CanExecute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.icommand.canexecute.aspx) method of the command will determine if the button is to be enabled or disabled.

Another approach is expose an `IsEnabled` property in your ItemViewModel, then bind the IsEnabled property on the button to it.

If you need to bind to a property in the parent ViewModel, you could get to it from the template in several approaches.

Here are some:

```
<UserControl x:Class="MyControl" x:Name="this" ...>

<...>
  <DataTemplate>
    <Grid>
      <Button
        IsEnabled="{Binding DataContext.IsEnabled, ElementName=this}"/>
      <Button
       IsEnabled="{Binding DataContext.IsEnabled, 
 RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type MyControl}}}"
    </Grid>
  </DataTemplate>
</...>
</UserControl>
```